# how can i create a dynamic Model/Object for the dataobject

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am trying to get the Data from Mongodb whose Model/Domain is unknown.
Can i get that using Mongo Template.
e.g.

```
mongoTemplate.find(query,<Dynamic Class?>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DBObject`. If you take a look at its implementations (`BasicDBObject`...)  it's an `HashMap` (key/values) containing all fields:

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

DBObject query  = new BasicDBObject("field", "value");
DBCursor dbCursor = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collectionName").find(query); 

Iterator<DBObject> iterator = dbCursor.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Object value = iterator.next().get("otherfield");
}
```